# How to programmatically load a different path/component at the current url/path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have `ComponentA` at path `/a`. Say I navigate to `/a` in my web app. Now if I want to load another path `/b/:b/c/:c` that is handled by a different set of root/child components, but at the current url/path, how would I do it? I know this goes against the norm but I have some strong reasons to do so.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Effectively, inside `ComponentA`, I want to do something like the following without changing the URL:

```
this.props.router.push('/b/:b/c/:c');
```

I want to load the entire component tree corresponding to the above path but at the current URL.

I know the values for `:b` and `:c` only inside `ComponentA`, so I can't really define this as multiple paths in the router.

Comment: if you're not using the path, you probably want to use a solution other than react-router...

Comment: i'm using all the paths mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) method for `<Route>` component to change rendered component without changing route.

```
<Router>
    <Route
        exact
        path="/Component1"
        render={() => {
            if (component === 1)
                return <Component1 setComponent={setComponent} />;
            else return <Component2 />;
        }}
    />
    <Route exact path="/Component2" component={Component2} />
</Router>
```

And here is working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-component-x5qzo). Go to https://x5qzo.csb.app/Component1 and push button to change component under the same route.